# Remove a certain word in a file

Tags: text-processing

How do I remove just `abcd11.gmail.com` and `*test1:` from line 1
and `abcd14.gmail.com` and `*fortest2:` from line 2 and `abcd19.gmail.com` and `*asatesteg:` from line 2 from below leaving the remaining as is? I have thousands of lines in a file like this:

```
May 23 03:44:02 abcd11.gmail.com x.x.x.x.x: *test1: May 23 04:46:21.032: #TEST1_ENTRY:4105 THIS is a test1    
May 23 03:44:02 abcd14.gmail.com x.x.x.x.x: *fortest2: May 23 04:46:21.032: #TEST2_ENTRY:4105 THIS is a test2 
May 23 03:44:02 abcd19.gmail.com x.x.x.x.x: *asatesteg: May 23 04:46:21.032: #TESTEG_ENTRY:4105 THIS is a testeg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sed` substitution

```
$ sed -e 's/abcd[0-9]*//g' -e 's/*test[0-9]*://g' file
```

Where `abcd[0-9]*` matches every `abcd` followed by a number, same with `*test[0-9]*:`

Answer (score 1):

A solution using cut:

```
cat $FILE | cut -d' ' -f4,6 --complement
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for all your reply... i did try above options with sed, but it dint work.. but when i did cut i am able to achieve the result partially... *test1 and *test2 .. are not getting removed but abcd1 and abcd2 is gone.. any inputs please?

Comment: @Ram It works in my machine with the sample file in your question! Could you double check if the actual file is exactly the same as the one you have in your question format wise?

Comment: May·23·13:12:15·abcd1·x.x.x.x.x.·:·*test1:·May·2016$                                                                                                                                                                                          
May·23·13:12:15·abcd2·x.x.x.x.x.·:·*test2:·May·2016$

Comment: This is how the file looks like when I open it in Emacs in white space mode. Dots are spaces. Yours might be different!

Comment: May 23 03:44:02 abcd11.gmail.com x.x.x.x.x: *test1: May 23 04:46:21.032: #TEST1_ENTRY:4105 THIS is a test1                                     
              May 23 03:44:02 abcd14.gmail.com x.x.x.x.x: *fortest2: May 23 04:46:21.032: #TEST2_ENTRY:4105 THIS is a test2                                   
              May 23 03:44:02 abcd19.gmail.com x.x.x.x.x: *asatesteg: May 23 04:46:21.032: #TESTEG_ENTRY:4105 THIS is a testeg

Comment: i try to give seperate lines but its taking up all together....line 1 ends with This is a test1 and same way for line 2 This is a test2 and same for line 3

Comment: Better to update your question with this. It is hard to follow in the comment!

Comment: @Ram OK now try my updated answer! ;)

Comment: That worked like a charm :) Thanks so much.. there are few entries that doesnt have the entry *test1: but for now it seems to be ok..

Comment: Good. Usually cut command is best when its input is having same format on each line (almost similar to yours). With complex inputs you should use `sed` or `awk` or similar.

Comment: looks like most of the required text are being disacarded. i wll have to work with sed or awk on this

Answer (score 0):

if you need to remove always the same sentence you can try

```
sed -e 's/abcd[0-9]*//g' -e 's/*test[0-9]*://g' file.ext
```

this show you the output in the stdout if you want save this output simple add the <kbd>></kbd> to the finel of the instruction or <kbd>>></kbd> to append the content to another file

```
sed -e 's/abcd[0-9]*//g' -e 's/*test[0-9]*://g' file.ext>new_file.ext
sed -e 's/abcd[0-9]*//g' -e 's/*test[0-9]*://g' file.ext>>new_file.ext
```

then you can remove the old file and replace whit the new

```
rm file.ext
mv new_file.ext file.ext
```